# When to use "setBlockOnOpen" and what does it do exactly?

Tags: dialog, jface

My application has one base Dialog that opens from the OTB Application.
Then I have 4 Dialogs that opens from button clicks in the base Dialog.

I am trying to decide if I need to use setBlockOnOpen, but I am not 100% what it does exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setBlockOnOpen(true)` is supposed to stop processing after the `open()` method and wait until the Dialog is closed to continue processing.

`setBlockOnOpen(false)` allows your code to continue processing after the `open()` method.